# clojure project for Heroku: procfile and organization

Tags: heroku, clojure

I have a single web application in clojure that is running on Heroku, but I want to create some worker processes.  Currently, my procfile says this:

```
web: java $JVM_OPTS -cp target/myapp-standalone.jar clojure.main -m myapp.web
```

Am I correct in assuming that I can simply create a new namespace "worker.clj" within the clojure project, and by amending the procfile to the following, that the new class/process would start up on a worker dyno?

```
web: java $JVM_OPTS -cp target/myapp-standalone.jar clojure.main -m myapp.web
worker: java $JVM_OPTS -cp target/myapp-standalone.jar clojure.main -m myapp.worker
```

Is this the right approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as long as you have a -main function in your new namespace, this will work.

Comment: It seems that an alternate approach would be to have a separate Heroku app for each worker process, although I don't see Heroku recommending this anywhere.  Is there a reason not to do this if the code base is truly separate for each process?